# GestureDetector.OnGestureListener overridden methods for Android API 33 makes my application crash (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using GestureDetector.OnGestureListener interface on my Activity.
It was working fine with Android API 32 but after updating the Android API level from 32 to 33, onScroll method requires its motionEvent parameters to remove '?' already causing my application to crash when it receives null inputs.

Please see below for the current interface:

```
    override fun onScroll(
    e1: MotionEvent,
    e2: MotionEvent,
    distanceX: Float,
    distanceY: Float
): Boolean {
    return false
}
```

Before, e1 and e2 are nullable..
What should I do with this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, and unfortunately the only way to fix this seems to be to convert your OnGestureListener back to Java.

In that way, you will not crash on null values. Remember (if you need to!) to SuppressWarning on null-checks about MotionEvents by using:

`@SuppressWarnings("ConstantConditions")`

Comment: Thanks! I also think that this is the only way for now...